set hostname in AWS EC2 instance using boto3
How do I set the hostname / servername in here ?
instance_params = {
    "ImageId": image.id.strip(),
    "InstanceType": instance_type,
    "KeyName": key_pair,
    "UserData": userdata,
    "NetworkInterfaces": [
        {
            "AssociatePublicIpAddress": True,
            "DeleteOnTermination": True,
            "DeviceIndex": 0,
            "SubnetId": subnet.id,
            "Groups": [security_group.id],
        }
    ],
    "Placement": {
        'AvailabilityZone': str(AvailabilityZone) if AvailabilityZone else None,
    },
    "BlockDeviceMappings": elastic_blob_storage
}

instance = ec2_resource.create_instances(**instance_params, MinCount=1, MaxCount=1)[0]


You forgot to explain what's wrong with the current code. Any errors?

Not an error - the deployed EC2's instance's server name should be the hostname that I want to set it to.

Apparently this has to be done in the terminal via SSH
# User data script to set the hostname
hostname = "your-server-name"  # Replace with your desired hostname
userdata_script = f"""#!/bin/bash
hostnamectl set-hostname {hostname}

